# why does shell sort outperform heap sort with large arrays?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, heapsort, shellsort

This is part of an assignments in which we have to compare different sorting algorithms. In order to get an unbiased testing processed I applied some basic concepts of statistics. Instead of running a single test I executed a sample of tests with different array sizes. The sample size is constant, 100, and the number of elements per round varied: one thousand, ten thousand, one-hundred thousand, one million and ten million elements respectively and the arrays were randomly filled.

Due to the restrictions of insertion sort, it wasn’t tested after one-hundred thousand elements. The number of comparisons and array accesses that every algorithm performed were recorded as well.

At the end of the report shell sort outperforms heap sort. The reasons are not clear to me. Might it have to do with the way the arrays were filled (with random numbers)?

[image: average running time with an array of 10 million elements]

This is the code used for both algorithms:

```
// source: Data Structures and Problem Solving Using C++ 2nd Edition
// page 329
void sortingAlgs::shellSort(std::vector<int>& array, int n) {
    for (int gap{static_cast<int>(n/2)}; gap > 0;
         gap = gap == 2 ? 1 : static_cast<int>(gap / 2.2)) { // floor
        for (int i{gap}; i < n; i++) {
            int temp = array[i];
            int j = i;

            for (; j >= gap && temp < array[j-gap]; j -= gap) {
                array[j] = array[j-gap];
            }
            array[j] = temp;
        }
}
}


// source: http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/
// source: Introduction to Algorithms page 154
    void sortingAlgs::max_heapify(std::vector<int>& array, int n, int i) {
    int largest = i;      // Initialize largest as root
    int l = 2*i + 1;  // left = 2*i + 1
    int r = 2*i + 2;  // right = 2*i + 2

    // If left child is larger than root
    if (l < n && array[l] > array[largest])
        largest = l;

    // If right child is larger than largest so far
    if (r < n && array[r] > array[largest])
        largest = r;

    // If largest is not root
    if (largest != i) {
        std::swap(array[i], array[largest]);
        // Recursively heapify the affected sub-tree
        max_heapify(array, n, largest);
    }
}

// source: http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/
// source: Introduction to Algorithms page 160
void sortingAlgs::heapSort(std::vector<int>& array, int n) {
    // Build heap (re-arrange array)
    for (int i = (n / 2) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        max_heapify(array, n, i);
    }

    // One by one extract an element from heap
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // Move current root to end
        std::swap(array[0], array[i]);
        // call max heapify on the reduced heap
        max_heapify(array, i, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see similar behavior for my implementations on large data arrays (10^7-10^8 ints): QuickSort as 1x, MergeSort, ShellSort ~1.5x, HeapSort ~ 2x time. Note that HeapSort is not cache-friendly (access to memory is not sequential)

Comment: I can't say exactly why heapsort would be slower, but MBo's comment about cache friendliness might be the key. Also note that, whereas both Shellsort and Quicksort might be faster in many (most?) cases, they do suffer from a worst case complexity of O(n^2). Heapsort, on the other hand, has worst case complexity of O(n log n). Which is why heapsort is the backup sorting method in Introsort: it can't be made to exhibit pathological behavior.

Comment: The heapsort is not an ideal heapsort. The heapify part should start at the end, work it's way back to the beginning, and be iterative.  After the initial heapify, sift down is used. Take a look at [wiki example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Pseudocode) .